What are reasons for data loss when using android room with jetpack compose?
When I updated my fairphone from android 12 to android 13 and I launched my own android todo app (sourcecode: MainActivity.kt) all my todo lists and tasks were gone.
Via intellij I accessed the sqlite file and discovered that all tables were in fact empty.
I installed my app via the "run app" in intellij and selecting my physical phone connected via wifi. Could this style of installation caused the data loss?
How do I prevent data loss in the future? I never experienced this from any other app, but maybe they weren't written with room, hilt and jetpack-compose?

When you install an app using IntelliJ's "Run App" button, the app is sometimes uninstalled before the new version is installed. This can lead to data loss because SQLite databases and other app data are typically cleared during uninstallation unless explicitly preserved.
